# Does Google bot always treat dot as word separator?

Tags: google-search, googlebot, web-crawlers, search-results

One of our products is a grid control called iGrid, and we have two versions for two different platforms. One is iGrid ActiveX, the other is iGrid for .NET Framework WinForms called "iGrid.NET". At some point we noticed that in the snippets on Google's SERP the ".NET" suffix is treated as a standalone word. For example, we can see highlighted text in bold (what Google highlights looking at the search query) like this:

... iGrid.**NET** is an advanced **DataGridView alternative**.

Is that right? How to check whether Google treats "iGrid.NET" as two separate words? And if so, tell him not to do that?

Comment: The easiest way to check if Google treats two strings differently it to search for them. "igrid.net" and "igrid net" return slightly different search results, but only slightly.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that Google detected the term .NET in the word and .NET is a well established keyword for the .NET framework. As such it would have made the mistaken decision that the word was simply missing a space and added it as a spelling correction. Not much that can be done about fixing this though.